# Trying to understand a Mean and Standard Deviation Question

Tags: statistics

I am trying to understand this simple question relating to mean and standard deviation.

"I currently have $100$ employees in my firm and have found that the growth rate in the next $5$ years will be $12%$ a year with a standard deviation of $6%$."

That is all I know about the potential growth.

How do I predict the number of employees for each year from here on out?

Comment: Standard deviation means you have a 68% chance to gain between 6 to 18 employees a year, 95% chance to gain between 0 and 24 employees per year, and a 99.7% chance to gain between 0 and 30 employees per year.

Comment: @Jeff arguably it could be interpreted as a 99.7% chance to gain between $-6$ and $30$ employees (where gaining a negative number corresponds to losing that many).  There is no reason to stop at zero for this specific question.

Comment: @ OP, depending on what the specific distribution is (many of these questions assume a normal distribution), and depending on whether the amount gained one year is *independent* from the other years, letting $X$ be the random variable for how many employees you gain (regardless of specific distribution) and assuming each year is independent, the number of employees you have after $k$ years will be $100+kX$.  By linearity, you should expect to have $100+12k$ employees with a std dev of $6k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @JMoravitz:

Assuming annual growth values are independent, the expected number of employees $Em_k$ is $100+12k$, and the standard deviation will be $6\sqrt{k}$, plugging in $k=5$, we get:

$E[Em_5]=160,Var[Em_5]=180\to SD=6\sqrt{5}$

We can go a little further by using Chebyshev's inequality:

$P(|Em_5-160|\geq n6\sqrt{5})\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$